# How to declare custom variables in bitbake recipes having the same visibility like for instance ${bindir}?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am using [yocto bitbake](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.1.1/poky-ref-manual/poky-ref-manual.html) to build a custom linux image.

I have 2 `bitbake` recipes. `recipe-1` and `recipe-2`. `recipe-1` creates a directory in linux output image. The directory name is `mydir`

```
recipe-1

SUMMARY="Creates direcory"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir} /mydir"

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}/mydir
}
```

Lets come to `recipe-2`. `recipe-2` wants to place a file called `myfile` into `mydir`

```
recipe-2

SUMMARY="Wants to place a file in mydir created by recipe-1"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
DEPENDS = "recipe-1"

SRC_URI = " file://myfile"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install_append () {
    install -m 600 ${WORKDIR}/myfile ${D}/mydir  # bibake build complains that mydir is not found
}
```

**Problem:**
In the base recipe I have mentioned `recipe-2` after `recipe-1` since `recipe-2` depends on `recipe-1`. That is fine but bitbake build complains that `mydir` is not recognised. I understand the problem. I need to make `mydir` visible to `recipe-2`. How can I do that?

**Question:**
Can I make `mydir` which is an output of `recipe-1`, be a global variable in my recipe build system? A global variable like `${bindir}`, `${datadir}` etc? If I can do this as a part of building `recipe-1`, then that could be an elegant solution?

So, I wish to use a custom variable lets say `${mydir}` in `do_install_append` of `recipe-2`? And do something like this in `do_install_append` of `recipe-2`.

```
install -m 600 ${WORKDIR}/myfile ${D}/${mydir}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Installation destinations are separate for each recipe and always empty at the beginning of the installation, so you need to create any directories in there. What other recipes do has no consequence.

If you want to set ${mydir} from a single location, put it into a class, and make each recipe inherit that class.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am looking at declaring `${mydir}` in a class and inherit it. Its quite strange that I have to inherit a class file just to use a path that a previously built recipe has created. Can this be done with an include variable?

Answer (score 3):

You can place some variable mydir to .inc file and include to both recipes with [require directive](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#require-inclusion).

Comment: This seems to have the thing I was looking for